# Suppress Pause Reason Question in a Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, visual-workflow

### Context

- We have a Screen Flow built in Lightning Flow Builder.
- The flow is exposed to members of the public through being embedded in a Lightning Aura Component placed on a page in a Community.
- When the user pauses the flow, they get presented with the pop-up asking for the reason that they paused the flow. In our particular use case, a reason for pausing is meaningless and so this question adds confusion to the user experience.

Additionally:

- `Let users pause flows` is enabled in the org.
- `Enable Lightning runtime for flows` is enabled in the org.

---

### Questions

**1. Is it possible to suppress or disable the pop-up asking for a pause reason, either for a specific flow or all of them in an org, whilst retaining the pause flow functionality?**

*(By pause flow functionality, I mean that a paused flow interview record is created and an `onstatuschange` event is fired.)*

**2. What is the best way, if it is even possible, to suppress this pop-up given that it embedded in a lightning aura component on a community page, most likely using some code solution?**

*(Just hiding the modal using CSS or other means is not good enough as doing so will likely not fire the `onstatuschange` event)*

---

### Unsuccessful Solutions

I attempted to, when the pause button was pressed on the flow screen, destroy the flow component or similar. This was unsuccessful as no `onstatuschange` event was fired until the OK button on the pop-up is clicked and so I was unable to trigger any action from this.